# -webkit-transform: No effect and background turns white

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, transform

I created a `span` using jQuery. After creation, the `span` has to be zoomed for a short amount of time. I am using CSS classes to achieve the desired effect. It works in Firefox and Opera, but not in webkit browsers. Why?

Here is a testcase:

```js
var i = 0;

$(".link").click(function() {
  i++;

  $("#boxes").append("<span class='box' id='" + i + "'>Test</span>");
  $(".box").fadeIn(500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".box[id = " + i + "]").addClass("zoom");
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".box[id = " + i + "]").removeClass("zoom");
  }, 900);
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.box {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.zoom {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.6);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
  -o-transform: scale(1.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Add box</a>

<div id="boxes"></div>
```

In webkit-browsers, my background image (not present in the fiddle) just disappears for a second and then comes back - no zoom, no nothing. As you can see, I used -webkit-transform, so there has to be another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

- Option 1

**
Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/Udhby/4/
Note the css change. Since you are inserting span which is an inline element, the transform property is not working somehow in webkit. Hence try adding display:inline-block to the zoom class

**

- Option 2

**

Instead of using spans make use of divs. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Udhby/5/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, transform on inline elements isn't working in webkit-browsers. Now I just assign `display: inline-block;` after the fade. Do you also know why the background image disappears while the transform is active?

Comment: Glad your prob was solved, accept the answer if it worked for you so that others know what the workaround is.